# Spherical Harmonics on $S^3$

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, quaternions, homotopy-groups-of-sphere

My understanding is that harmonic analysis on the circle ($S^1$) leads to Fourier Series/Integrals whereas harmonic analysis on the sphere ($S^2$) leads to Spherical Harmonics.  If we take the next logical step, what would be a "Fourier-like" set of square-integrable orthogonal functions defined on the three-sphere ($S^3$)?  Any references?

[Edit] I added a comment below as an attempt to clarify my question and have it re-opened.

Comment: See Zonal Spherical Functions.

Comment: $S^3=\mathrm{SU}(2)$. [Peter-Weyl theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter–Weyl_theorem#Decomposition_of_square-integrable_functions).

Comment: In the general setting of a compact Riemannian manifold these are eigenfunctions of the Laplace-Beltrami operator. See e.g. Chavel's book *Eigenvalues in Riemannian Geometry*.

Comment: For $\mathbb{S}^n$ you get the spherical harmonics as restrictions to the spheres of homogeneous harmonic polynomials in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Higher_dimensions for a quick discussion.

Comment: My apologies if my question seems off-topic or not research-level.  To clarify, I am looking for a set of functions similar to what is listed at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics but specifically for $S^3=SU(2)$ (not $S^n, n>3$).  Even more specifically, I am curious as to how this set of functions gets simplified when expressed in Cartesian vs Hyper-spherical vs Hopf coordinates.  I would imagine that the Hopf coordinate system would expose some sort of symmetry that would simplify the derivation of said Spherical harmonics but I cannot derive this myself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The story for square integrable functions and differential forms is clearly explained in G. Folland, *Harmonic analysis of the deRham complex on the sphere*, **J. Reine Ang. Math.**, 398, 1989, 130-143.